# callback method in javascript

Tags: javascript

Write a function that accepts a callback method and returns a function that will execute
only if all the parameters passed to it are defined, otherwise it returns nothing.
Here's what I wrote
why is not it working?

```js
function sumof(checkof) {
  sum = 0
  for (a in this.myNumbers)
    if (checkof(a) == 1)
      sum += a
  else
    return null
  return sum

}

function check(a) {
  if (a == null)
    return 0
  else
    return 1

}

function init() {
  let myNumbers = [22, 1, 8, 4, 17];
  var x = myNumbers.sumof(check)
  alert(x)
}
init()
```

Comment: You're failing to tell us what exactly is wrong – "why isn't it working" is never really enough.

Comment: (But why would you imagine `myNumbers.sumof(...)` would work?)

Comment: change it to `sumof(myNumbers)`\

Comment: Your function is not a method of your array. You'll need to separate them in the function call.

Comment: @Itamar no, because the first argument to sumof is supposed to be a callback function.

Comment: should it accept ONLY the CB?

Comment: @Itamar if you're addressing this to me, it would need to pass both, because both are needed. See my answer below. In future please tag the person you are talking to in your comment.

Comment: @ADyson I am addressing it to Shulamit,  the OP

Answer (score 2):

`myNumbers.sumof` doesn't work because `sumof` is a standalone function, not part of `Array`.

`this.myNumbers` also makes no sense because myNumbers isn't global.

The simplest solution is to pass myNumbers into your sumof function:

```js
function sumof(checkof, myNumbers) {
  sum = 0
  for (a in myNumbers)
    if (checkof(a) == 1)
      sum += a
  else
    return null
  return sum

}

function check(a) {
  if (a == null)
    return 0
  else
    return 1

}

function init() {
  let myNumbers = [22, 1, 8, 4, 17];
  var x = sumof(check, myNumbers)
  alert(x)
}
init()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling it like a array property method. but you have defined that function as a standalone function. you should add your function as a array property method.

```js
Array.prototype.sumof = function(checkof) {
    if ( ! this.length ) {
        return null;
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        a = this[i];
        if (checkof(a) == 1) {
            sum += a;
        }
    }
    return sum;
};


function check(a) {
    if (a == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;

}

function init() {
    let myNumbers = [22, 1, 8, 4, 17];
    var x = myNumbers.sumof(check);
    console.log(x);
    myNumbers = [22, 1, null, 4, 17];
    x = myNumbers.sumof(check);
    console.log(x);
}
init();
```

also if you are using Array property method, you should avoid using for..in. because when you looping through `this`, it will also have your new method too. use `for` with array length.